# prevent thread starvation Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have some function which does some file writing. The semaphore is for limiting a number of threads to 2. The total number of threads are 3. How can I prevent from the 3 threads a starvation? Is the queue is an option for that?

```
import time
import threading

sema = threading.Semaphore(2)


def write_file(file,data):
    sema.acquire()
    try:
        f=open(file,"a")
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
    finally:
        sema.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a thread is waiting to acquire the semaphore, either of the other two threads will be done writing and release the semaphore.

If you are worried that if there is a lot of writing going on, the writers might reacquire the semaphore before the waiting thread is notified. This can not happen, I think.

The [Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) object in Python (2.7) uses a [`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Condition). The Condition adds waiting threads (actually a lock, which the waiting thread is blocking on) to the end of an `waiters` list and when notifying threads, the [notified threads are taken from the beginning of the list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/threading.py#L386). So the list acts like a FIFO-queue.

It looks something like this:

```
def wait(self, timeout=None):
    self.__waiters.append(waiter)
    ...

def notify(self, n=1):
    ...
    waiters = self.__waiters[:n]
    for waiter in waiters:
        waiter.release()
    ...
```

My understanding, after reading the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/threading.py#L386), is that Python's Semaphores are FIFO. I couldn't find any other information about this, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This changed at some point.  In Python 3.11 for example, the waiter list in a `Condition` is a `deque`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b5dbd1f237a013defdaf0799e0a1a3cbd0b13cc/Lib/threading.py#L258

Answer (score 2):

I have to object to the accepted question. It is true that `Condition` queues the `wait`s, but the more important part is when it tries to [acquire the `Condition` lock](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/threading.py#L461).

The order in which threads are released is [*not* deterministic](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.wait)

> The implementation may pick one at random, so the order in which blocked threads are awakened should not be relied on.

In the case of three threads, there I agree, it's very unlikely that two are trying to acquire the lock at the same time (one working, one in `wait`, one acquiring the lock), but there still might be interferences.

A good solution for your problem IMO would be a thread that's single purpose is to read your data from a queue and write it to a file. All other threads can write to the queue and continue working.